# Cannot bind metadata to engine for SQLAlchemy in Pyramid application

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Can somebody please explain to me why this is not working:

My **init**.py file :

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid_jinja2 import renderer_factory
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config

from .models import (DBSession, 
                Base,
                )

def main(global_config, **settings):
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    DBSession.configure(bind = engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine

    config = Configurator(settings = settings)
    config.include('pyramid_jinja2')

    #The views/routes are added here
    config.add_static_view('static', 'static')
    config.add_static_view('scripts', 'scripts')

    config.add_route("my_route", '/')
    config.add_route("sign_in", "/sign_in")
    config.add_route("sign_up", "/sign_up")
    config.add_route("main_page", "/{username}")
    config.scan()

    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

My models.py file:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.schema import Table
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import (scoped_session, sessionmaker, synonym, relation, backref)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, DeferredReflection
from zope.sqlalchemy import ZopeTransactionExtension


DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension = ZopeTransactionExtension()))
Base = declarative_base(cls=DeferredReflection)


#Define your models here
class User(Base):
    __table__ = Table('users', Base.metadata, autoload = True)
```

I did exactly as is stipulated in the tutorial for Pyramid (which is to use Base.metadata.bind = engine in **init**.py) and I still get the error :

"sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: No engine is bound to this Table's MetaData. Pass an engine to the Table via autoload_with='someengine', or associate the MetaData with an engine via metadata.bind='someengine'"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `autoload` before your engine is bound. SQLA tries to reflect the `users` table at the module init time, even though the metadata does not have any engine associated yet.

The "fix" I had for this was two-fold - a custom table factory:

```
def AutoloadedTable(*args, **kwargs):
    rv = Table(*args, **kwargs)
    rv.deferred_autoloading = True
    return rv
```

that just stuffs `deferred_autoloading` property, and the following snippet **after** the engine was created:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import reflection

inspector = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
for i in list(metadata.tables.values()):
    if getattr(i, 'deferred_autoloading', False):
        inspector.reflecttable(i, None)
```

Comment: and do you happen to know what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this issue using the instructions below:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative.html#using-reflection-with-declarative

and adding

Base.prepare(engine) to my main function in **init**.py file